# Find feeds that haven't been updated in a while in Feedly

Tags: feedly

I've gathered quite a few feeds over the years (including a migration from the dear, departed Google Reader).

I usually keep my view to find only those feeds that have new content, but I've gathered a lot of cruft. I'd like to find and drop those feeds that haven't had a new post in, say, a year or so, and drop them.

Going to each and every feed to do this is not the preferred way to do this.

Is there a way I can find old and abandoned feeds?

Comment: this is a feature we're currently working on, to spot dead feeds or Dinosaurs how some say :)

Comment: @Petr: Good to hear. Any idea on a timeline for implementation?